# Replacing all patterns in a string

Tags: .net, string, replace

In VB.NET / C#.NET want to replace all "%0D%0A%0D%0A" in a string with %0D%0A". I have tried

```
    stringtempA = Regex.Replace(stringtemp, "%0D%0A%0D%0A", "%0D%0A")
    stringtempA = Strings.Replace(stringtemp, "%0D%0A%0D%0A", "%0D%0A")
```

There are multiple  occurences in stringtemp. For example, there might be "%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A" and only the first occurence is replaced. How is this done with the Replace command? Is the issue caused by the percent signs? I so how do I escape them?

Comment: What is your expected output for `%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A`?

Comment: Use `stringtempA = Regex.Replace(stringtemp, "(%0D%0A)(%0D%0A)+", "$1")`

Comment: Sorry, that wasnt a good example.  In the string I want ever two occurrences reduced to one. %0D%0A%0D%0A changed to %0D%0A

Comment: Thank you Alex K! I don't understand it, but your Regex answer works!

Answer (score 1):

Use the replace function from the string variable itself.

**c#**

```
stringtempA = stringtemp.Replace(@"%0D%0A%0D%0A", @"%0D%0A");
```

**vb.net**

```
stringtempA = stringtemp.Replace("%0D%0A%0D%0A", "%0D%0A")
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. That works in C#, but not VB.net. It has to be something with the default behavior of Replace and the percent sign in the string needs to be escaped?

Comment: @ sign escapes all special characters in c# version.I've edited the vb.net version